# Addition in signed magnitude system in Computer Science

Tags: computer-science

I am having difficulty understanding the addition in signed magnitude system. I read the Wikipedia, my notes and I still dont understand it.

for example : 
what is the addition of `1100 1001 + 1111 1111` in a **signed magnitude** 8-bit system. I know that if the sign bits of operands are the same we simply add the magnitudes. But the result will be different from addition in 2's complement system.

What if the sign bits are different ? then what is the sign of the result?

here is an example :

```
- 1 | 101 1100
+ 0 | 100 0010
  --------------
- 1 | 001 1010
```

the sign of the result is `1` because the first operand has the larger magnitude ? is this the correct way?

Comment: Your example overflows (both are negative, larger than 2^7 in magnitude, result magnitude is larger that 2^8)

Comment: how did you know that the first example is overflow ? the answer to the first example will be `1100 1000`, but it also has a carry out , is that how you determine signed overflow for the magnitude system?

Comment: In sign-magnitude, the first bit is sign. You have to consider carry out of 7 bits (not 8) for overflow.

Comment: Sorry, messed up. It is larger than 2^6, and thus magnitude greater than 2^7 in my first comment-

Comment: okay, it makes sense now that consider carry out of the 7 bits. but I am still now sure about different sign operands, looking at my example, is the result correct ? or should it be `0001 1010` ? and no sign overflow

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly how you do addition by hand: If the signs are the same, add the mangitudes; is they differ, check which one has larger magnitude (that is the sign of the result), and substract the smaller magnitude from the larger.